# Copy and Paste only unprotected cells taking too long

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this macro but it really takes too long to run. I can't figure out how to make it go faster.

What it does: it checks every cell in a worksheet (Roh), if it's protected (locked), then it will skip this cell and go to the next one, if it's unprotected, it will copy and paste the value from the other worksheet (Import). Both sheets have the same formating. I use it to update the current project to a new version. A hard copy-paste won't work, because some formulas change. 
Can anyone please help me find a faster way?

Thanks! :)

```
Sub import()

Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

StartTime = Timer

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Roh")

If Sheets("Roh").ProtectContents = True Then

    Worksheets("Roh").Activate
    For i = 202 To 3408
        For j = 5 To 53
            If Cells(i, j).Locked = False Then
                destSht.Cells(i, j) = srcSht.Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End If

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox "Dieser Code wurde in " & MinutesElapsed & " Minuten erfolgreich ausgeführt.", vbInformation


End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end. This should help to improve speed.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly! Instead of waiting 55 min, now it takes only 3s! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed enhancement you can add these two things at beggining and end of your file:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
xxxxxxxxxxx
{ Code }
xxxxxxxxxxx
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

ScreenUpdating disable visualization of operation in real time (when you copy-paste on different sheet, avoid the blinking screen for example).

Calculation avoid to recalculate data at each operation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using arrays to speed your routine up instead. Just update `inRng` with your `Import` Range

```
Option Explicit
Sub import()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim inRng As Range
    Dim inArr As Variant, lockArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim MinutesElapsed As String

    StartTime = Timer

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set srcSht = .Sheets("Import")
        Set destSht = .Sheets("Roh")
    End With

    With srcSht
        Set inRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)))
    End With

    inArr = inRng.Value2
    ReDim outArr(LBound(inArr, 1) To UBound(inArr, 1), LBound(inArr, 2) To UBound(inArr, 2))

    For i = 1 To inRng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To inRng.Columns.Count
            If Not inRng.Cells(i, j).Locked Then
                outArr(i, j) = inArr(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    With destSht
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(outArr, 2), UBound(outArr, 1)).Value2 = outArr
    End With

    MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    MsgBox "Dieser Code wurde in " & MinutesElapsed & " Minuten erfolgreich ausgeführt.", vbInformation

End Sub
```